# Dynamically process Cubes in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssas

I have three "Analysis Services Processing Tasks" in my Control Flow. Each one processes a different Cube. Now the problem is i want to control them on execution time. I need to pass in a parameter to control execution of Cube Processing. This could be any combination like Run Task 1 then Task 3 and Again Task One

I would like this to be configurable on Run time as CMD parameter or DB or XML based config.

I am thinking if i store a sequence like 1,2,3,1,3 in Database and fetch it on runtime and store it a variable and use a foreach to iterate through this and run the tasks inside that loop?

Can anybody give any suggestion or share his/her experience

Thanks a lot

Comment: SSIS can easily do what you described but usually I find these "requirements" resolve down to a single optimal sequence of running once the app is productionized, so this may be a waste of time :-)

Comment: Solved: Add a database table to hold connection strings and iterating through connection string through foreach loop

Comment: @InTheWorldOfCodingApplications You can add that as an answer and accept it. You'll get some points and other users will know the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a database table to hold connection strings and iterate through  connection strings by using a  foreach loop